# The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. On INSERT

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I know there are many other questions like mine but none of the answers have helped me so far. Im creating a mvc website using Code First. So far so good. The database have been created and now I want to insert some data using the code. But keep getting that damn error as if I didnt have a primary key. I can easily insert data into the table by using MSSQL.
The clinic already exists in the database and im using the correct values for the foreign keys.

How the table was created:

```
//CreateTable(
            "dbo.Department",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Clinic_Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Title = c.String(),
                    Description = c.String(),
                    LastModifiedAt = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    CreatedAt = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Clinic", t => t.Clinic_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Clinic_Id);
```

The Department object:

```
    public class Department
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Clinic_Id { get; set; }
    public Clinic Clinic { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
    public List<Practitioner> Practitioners { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public Department()
    {
    }
}
```

I create the object

```
    private void CreateDepartment(Clinic clinic, int departmentNumber)
    {
        Department department = new Department();
        department.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        department.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        department.Description = "Description";
        department.LastModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;
        department.Clinic_Id = clinic.Id;
        department.Title = "Title";
        DepartmentList.Add(department);
    }
```

And then try to Add it to my context:

```
DepartmentList.ForEach(x => context.Departments.Add(x));
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You can't insert a field marked as an identity. It is usually an auto-generated field like an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while creating table
u are mentioning

```
Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
```

so it will consider as auto generated field

Thats why it is giving this error when you try to assign it manually.
If you need to assign it manually modify your object class definition with this

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```